# python gspread google spreadsheet keeping connection alive

Tags: python, gspread

I'm updating my spreadsheets using `gspread`, the process takes about an hour, i have about 200 spreadsheets. It seems about 30 minutes into the updating the sheets, the connection drops. Is there a way to keep the login alive? I thought I was keeping the connection alive because I'm opening and writing to different sheets about every 30 seconds.

I can use a `try` statement and if it bombs re-login. I was wondering if anybody had a better way?

I'm used to using the simple example from `gspread` example of:

```
gc = gspread.login('thedude@abid.es', 'password')
sht1 = gc.open_by_key('0BmgG6nO_6dprdS1MN3d3MkdPa142WFRrdnRRUWl1UFE')
```

How do I turn this into a keep alive connection login to arrive at `sht1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keeping alive connection you should use persistent connection.

So if you check main document:

http://burnash.github.io/gspread/#gspread.Client

You will see the `gspread.login` method is instance of `Client`. and `Client` can accept `http` headers.

http://burnash.github.io/gspread/#gspread.httpsession.HTTPSession

Now add this header in your connection : `Connection: Keep-Alive`

```
import gspread
headers = gspread.httpsession.HTTPSession(headers={'Connection':'Keep-Alive'})
con = gspread.Client(auth=('you@gmail.com','password'),http_session=headers)
con.login()
con.open_by_key('....')
```

Then when you get print of session headers:

```
print con.session.headers
Out[5]: {'Authorization': u'GoogleLogin auth=xxxxxxx', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'}
```

For persistent connection details have a look into these links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

For codes details of `gspread httpsession` have a look into:

https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/httpsession.py

Comment: can you show me a few lines of code for example? how do i login with persistent connection? I looked thru the link and still don't understand. I did try to dig through the code.

Comment: @jason_cant_code sure! I updated my post. check it ;)

Comment: @jason_cant_code have a look into persistent connection image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HTTP_persistent_connection.svg

Comment: so the connection will be alive til my program is finished? how does it "close"?

Comment: @jason_cant_code could you update your post and add your codes?

Comment: how do i then `open_by_key`? I have this code `self.gc=con.login()
            self.cDB=self.gc.open_by_key(Gsheets.cDB_key)` getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_by_key'`

Comment: @jason_cant_code that error refers to your coding. just try simple and check it. I tried it via ipython , it shows me `open_by_key` and `open_by_url` for `con` variable. did you test my code?

Comment: I see it should be `con.open_by_key` not `con.login().open_by_key`

Comment: @jason_cant_code yes. it has `open_by_key` for `con` variable. but you need to login it before as I see in this example: http://burnash.github.io/gspread/#gspread.Client.open_by_key

Comment: @jason_cant_code yes. you are right. first `login` and then `open_by_key`. never do them at the same time. I updated my post.

Comment: Even after setting up the connection as a persistent connection Google will come back with a bad service line after enough time. Attempting to re-login with the con.login() does not solve it. Restarting the script will for a minute or two...

Comment: This method of authentication isn't supported anymore by Google. see this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2  .

Comment: Try this code: `import gspread;  from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials;  scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'];  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Pluss Inventory-7160481b4bc0.json', scope);   headers = gspread.httpsession.HTTPSession(headers={'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'});  gc = gspread.Client(auth=credentials, http_session=headers);  gc.login()`