# Gspread httperror when updating cell

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, gspread

For some reason I get: gspread.httpsession.HTTPError when trying to update a cell.

```
spreadsheet_name = raw_input("Please enter a spreadsheet url: ")
json_keys = json.load(open('keys.json'))
scopes = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentialss = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_keys['client_email'], 
json_keys['private_key'], scopes)
gcs = gspread.authorize(credentialss)
wkss = gcs.open_by_url(spreadsheet_name).sheet1
```

in one function returning wkss 
and then

```
time.sleep(3)
all_data = wkss.get_all_values()
row_track = 0
for rows in all_data:
    print str(row_track)
    for dd in data:
        if str(rows[5]) == str(dd[1]):
            pdb.set_trace()
            wkss.update_cell(row_track, 29, dd[2].strip())
            print str(row_track) + ", 24" 
            print "MATCH"
    row_track +=1
```

[python gspread google spreadsheet keeping connection alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568907/python-gspread-google-spreadsheet-keeping-connection-alive)

I found that but since I am accessing the worksheet by way where should I include the headers?  The client does not seem to like it if I follow that.

Comment: Is it something to do with multiple connections running?